# Java Spring Extender @Scheduled para ler um arquivo

Tags: java, spring, annotation, scheduler

Eu tenho tarefas para fazer assim que subo minha aplicação,  elas são executadas repetidamente dessa forma:

```
  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)  
  public void scheduleFixedRateTask() {
        System.out.println("Fixed rate task - " + System.currentTimeMillis()/10000);
  }
```

Porém algumas vezes eu preciso atualizar o intervalo de tempo e eu não queria ter que parar a aplicação toda vez para fazer isso. Então queria saber se existe um meio de extender o @Scheduled do spring para que ele leia algum arquivo de configuração, tem como?

Comment: você usa spring boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode parametrizar a annotation do Spring, fica um pouco diferente o parâmetro:

```
//fixedDelay task:
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${fixedDelay.in.milliseconds}")

//fixedRate task:
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${fixedRate.in.milliseconds}")

//A cron expression based task:
@Scheduled(cron = "${cron.expression}")
```

Ai basta adicionar a propriedade ao seu arquivo de configuração.

Fonte: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks

Comment: Vou tentar no fim de semana, se funfar marco sua resposta.

Comment: Não funcionou?!

Comment: scheduled funiona para Windows ?

Answer (score 0):

Atualizar propriedades do Spring com a aplicação rodando costuma ser um problema não trivial. Dessa forma muitas vezes acaba sendo mais fácil implementar esse tipo de agendamento de maneira programática:

```
@Autowired private TaskScheduler scheduler; 

private ScheduledFuture scheduledTask;

@PostConstruct
public void init() throws Exception {
    // Dispara com valor padrao, alternativamente 
    // isso pode ser lido do arquivo de propriedades
    scheduleFixedRateTask(10000L);
}

public void scheduleFixedRateTask(final long rate) {
    if (scheduledTask!= null) {
        // Em um código real você provavelmente quer fazer algo mais robusto
        // do que interromper a tarefa logo de cara.
        scheduledTask.cancel(true);
    } 
    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
          System.out.println("Fixed rate task - " + System.currentTimeMillis()/rate);
       }
    };
    scheduledTask= scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, rate);
}
```

Para casos de uso mais complexos [o Spring tem suporte ao Quartz](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-quartz-schedule), porém o Quartz é um canhão se sua aplicação não possui necessidade real de *jobs* persistente / transacionais / distribuídos.

---

**Fontes**:

1. [Spring Framework Reference - Task Execution and Scheduling](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)
2. [SOen - Creating Spring Framework task programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4499177/664577)
3. [SOen - How to cancel Spring timer execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868323/how-to-cancel-spring-timer-execution)
4. [Spring Scheduling: @Scheduled vs Quartz](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4385719/664577)